# Interview Question:- I have one table with following data in sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[T_COL](
    [COL1] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [COL2] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[T_COL] ([COL1], [COL2]) VALUES (N'A', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[T_COL] ([COL1], [COL2]) VALUES (N'A', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[T_COL] ([COL1], [COL2]) VALUES (N'A', 3)
INSERT [dbo].[T_COL] ([COL1], [COL2]) VALUES (N'B', 1)
INSERT [dbo].[T_COL] ([COL1], [COL2]) VALUES (N'B', 2)
INSERT [dbo].[T_COL] ([COL1], [COL2]) VALUES (N'B', 3)
```

The desired output should look like this:-

```
col1     col2
A         1
A         1,2
A         1,2,3
B         1
B         1,2
B         1,2,3
```

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking? If the numbers were 4,7,9 or any other combination would this change the output? How exactly is the output being formed?

Comment: Particularly what determines the order of rows and the order of contents of the col2 columns in the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a rolling string aggregate function. `STRING_AGG` doesn't allow `OVER()` clause, so a solution is to use a correlated subquery with `FOR XML` to generate the list.

```
SELECT
    T.COL1,
    RollingAggregate = STUFF (
        (
            SELECT
                ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), N.COL2)
            FROM
                [dbo].[T_COL] AS N
            WHERE
                N.COL1 = T.COL1 AND     -- Same letter
                N.COL2 <= T.COL2        -- Equal or lower number
            ORDER BY
                N.COL2
            FOR XML
                PATH('')
        ),
        1, 1, '') -- Remove leading comma
FROM
    [dbo].[T_COL] AS T
ORDER BY
    T.Col1,
    T.Col2
```

Result:

```
COL1    RollingAggregate
A       1
A       1,2
A       1,2,3
B       1
B       1,2
B       1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a contrived question for an interview. SQL was not really designed for string handling and, as a result, queries involving string manipulation are sometimes a bit "clumsy".

```
WITH t1 AS
(
  SELECT col1, col2 AS x1, col2 + 1 AS x2, col2 + 2 AS x3 
  FROM t_col
),
t2 AS
(
  SELECT col1, CAST(x1 AS VARCHAR) AS the_result
  FROM t1
    UNION
  SELECT col1, CAST(x1 AS VARCHAR) + ',' + cast(x2 AS VARCHAR)
  FROM t1
    UNION
  SELECT col1, CAST(x1 AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CAST(x2 AS VARCHAR) + ',' + CAST(x3 AS VARCHAR)
  FROM t1
  WHERE x3 < 4
)
SELECT col1, the_result AS col2 FROM t2
WHERE LEFT(the_result, 1) = '1'
ORDER BY col1, RIGHT(the_result, 1);
```

Result:

```
col1   col2
----   ----
A      1
A      1,2
A      1,2,3
B      1
B      1,2
B      1,2,3
```

See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5ebe7062794acbb07ab21397d3b820db). Also, check out [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b166882a9be0c28c6b5e8c32a49f911a) which is more compliant with the SQL standard. A potential employer might be impressed with that?

Answer (score 0):

As it's SQL Server I might do it with a recursive CTE.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT [COL1],
         [COL2],
         CAST([COL2] AS VARCHAR(10)) AS [Combo]
  FROM [dbo].[T_COL]
  WHERE [COL2] = 1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT c.[COL1],
         t.[COL2],
         CAST(c.[Combo] + ',' + CAST(t.[COL2] AS VARCHAR) AS VARCHAR(10)) -- arbitrary length. Fits this example
  FROM CTE c
       JOIN [dbo].[T_COL] t ON c.[COL1] = t.[COL1] AND c.[COL2] + 1 = t.[COL2]
)

SELECT 
  [COL1] AS col1,
  [Combo] AS col2
FROM CTE
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Result

```
col1       col2
A          1
A          1,2
A          1,2,3
B          1
B          1,2
B          1,2,3
```

But I agree it's an oddly contrived problem. I might look else where if I saw this in an interview..